# Validate cell editing in Primefaces using a Validator

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a datatable as following :

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTablePlanningSalleAppareil"
             styleClass="dataTablePlanningSalleAppareil"
             editable="true" editMode="cell"
             value="#{beanPlanningSalleAppareil.getListPlanningSalleAppareilBySalleOrACAndDay(entry, jour.key)}"
             var="planning"
             sortBy="#{planning.heureDebut}">

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
            listener="#{beanPlanningSalleAppareil.onCellEdit}"
            update=":#{p:component('gestionPlanningSalleAppareilMessage')}">
    </p:ajax>

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="#{jour.value}" style="width:100px" />
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor rendered="#{planning.id != 0}" >
            <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{planning.heureDebut}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputMask mask="99:99" value="#{planning.heureDebut}"
                             required="true" maxlength="4"
                             requiredMessage="Heure de début : vous devez indiquer une valeur.">
                    <f:validator validatorId="planningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator" />
                    <f:attribute name="planningId" value="#{planning.id}" />
                </p:inputMask>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column  rendered='#{beanListPlanningSalleAppareil.acceuil.valeur eq "1"}'>
        <p:cellEditor rendered="#{planning.id != 0}">
            <f:facet name="output">
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{planning.formuleCremation.alias}" /></f:facet>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{planning.formuleCremation}" converter="#{formuleCremationConverter}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{beanPlanningSalleAppareil.formules}"
                                   var="formule"
                                   itemLabel="#{formule.alias}"
                                   itemValue="#{formule}" />
                    <f:validator validatorId="planningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator" />
                    <f:attribute name="planningId" value="#{planning.id}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column >
        <p:row>
            <p:commandLink rendered="#{planning.id != 0}"
                           action="#{beanPlanningSalleAppareil.setSelectedPlanning(planning)}"
                           oncomplete="suppressionConfirmation.show()" process="@this" ajax="true">
                <h:graphicImage styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" style="display: inline-block;"/>
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:row>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

this datatable is editable and I can edit two cells `planning.heureDebut` and `planning.formuleCremation`.

So what I want to do is to do some verifications before the update can be performed, and I will check on the current row and the new value of the cell, so to know which row I'm modifying I added an attribute as following :

```
<f:attribute name="planningId" value="#{planning.id}" />
```

And for that I created a this validator :

```
@FacesValidator("planningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator")
public class PlanningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator implements Validator {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PlanningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator.class);
    @Autowired
    private IPlanningSalleAppareilService planningSalleAppareilService;

    public PlanningSalleAppareilFormuleCremationValidator() {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
        WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext).
                                   getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().
                                   autowireBean(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) throws ValidatorException {

        int id = (int) uic.getAttributes().get("planningId");

        //The selected Salle or Appareil
        Object selectedObject = null;
        //Current Planning
        PlanningSalleAppareil planningSalleAppareil = planningSalleAppareilService.trouver(id);

        if(planningSalleAppareil.getAppareil() != null)
            selectedObject = planningSalleAppareil.getAppareil();
        if(planningSalleAppareil.getSalle() != null)
            selectedObject = planningSalleAppareil.getSalle();

        if(o instanceof FormuleCremation)
            planningSalleAppareil.setFormuleCremation((FormuleCremation) o);

        if(o instanceof String)
            planningSalleAppareil.setHeureDebut((String) o);

        if(selectedObject != null){
            String errorMessage = planningSalleAppareilService.validPlanningSalleAppareil(planningSalleAppareil,selectedObject);
            if(!errorMessage.equals("1")){
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(errorMessage);
                    msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what I'm doing is when I modify `planning.heureDebut` or `planning.formuleCremation` for the row that has the id I passed with `<f:attribute name="planningId" value="#{planning.id}" />` and I get it from the database as following :

```
int id = (int) uic.getAttributes().get("planningId");
PlanningSalleAppareil planningSalleAppareil = planningSalleAppareilService.trouver(id);
```

Then I set the new value I've edited to this `planningSalleAppareil` and then I call the verification function from the service.

So the behavior I'm getting is that when I edit some cell, my application saves the new value to the database before it calls the validator, so when it calls the validator, the validation will always fail since the service method will always get the object with the new value.

For example if I have a row like this :

```
planning.id = 1
planning.heureDebut = 18:00
...
```

and then when I edit the column for `planning.heureDebut` like this :

```
planning.heureDebut = 20:00
```

It should perform validation before it updates the new value for `planning.heureDebut` so it will call the service method `planningSalleAppareilService.trouver(id);` which will return a planning with `planning.heureDebut = 18:00`, but the service method returns a planning with `planning.heureDebut = 20:00` which means the update has been performed before it calls the validator.

So how can I prevent this to happen ? and how can I call the validation before the update ?

Comment: are `@Component
@Scope("view")` needed?

Comment: @Apostolos no Actually they are not required I just forgot to remove them

Comment: A clear [mcve] will increase chance in getting answers. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info About 70% of code provided so far doesn't seem to be relevant to the described problem at all. Non-English variable/method names are also major mind blocking slowdowns of reading code by experts not familiar with the foreign language. A 50-rep bonus is imo not worth the effort to spend about a hour of time to boil down a real MCVE out of the information provided so far. Additionally, more time is needed if non-Java EE APIs are used such as Spring (not all JSF experts use/know Spring).

Comment: As far as I know, you can not modify your object from the validator. This is because the object is passed-by-value, not by reference.